# Replace every dot with underscore if whitespace/newline not before and after

Tags: awk, sed

Let's say I have the following file

```
asdfa .a
xsf. asdfa
 . xasdf
asdfasfd.sadfa.
asdfa .a
xsf. asdfa
 . 3xasdf
asdfasfd2.sadfa.
```

And, I want to get this:

```
asdfa .a
xsf. asdfa
.xasdf
asdfasfd_sadfa.
asdfa .a
xsf. asdfa
 . 3xasdf
asdfasfd2_sadfa.
```

Basically, every dot has to be replaced with an underscore if all following conditions are true:

1. There is no blank character as well as tab before and after the dot.
2. The dot is not at the beginning of the line.
3. The dot is not at the end of the line.

**Update:**
So, far I could only come up with `sed 's/\./_/g'`. But, this replaces every dot.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump your to-do list. You show some code, we (maybe) try help fix it. We are not here to do your job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here `sed` shines

```
$ sed -r 's/(\S)\.(\S)/\1_\2/g' file
```

Comment: I suggest you use the `-E` option which is kinda more portable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick

```
sed -i 's/\(\w\)\(\.\)\(\w\)/\1_\3/g' mytextfile.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but you can enable the extended regex imho.